# How to search character U-FFFD (black diamond question mark) in NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, character

I have a problem. I want to change the black diamond question mark (U-FFFD) with white space. How could I search the character (black diamond question mark) so I can change it with white space? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\ufffd" withString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve black diamond with question mark.

just use this:

```
foreach($disp as $objs)
{

    $objs = preg_replace( '|[^.?,A-Za-z0-9-]+|', ' ', $objs);
    echo $objs;
}

// this will display character (.?A-Z AND 0-9) and replace char other than this.
```